# How can I modify the property of a Qgridlayout's widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have defined a 2X6 QGridlayout filled with Qlabels but later, I would like to change the labels text or properties to something else. How can I do that?

This is how I defined the Qgridlayout in pyqt4

```
gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
for i in range(1, 7):
        for j in range(1, 3):
            gridLayout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("label" + str(i) + str(j)), i, j)
```

Comment: `gridLayout.itemAtPosition(1, 1).widget()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to keep a reference of the labels created by the loop to use later like this:

```
gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
labels = {}
for i in range(1, 7):
    for j in range(1, 3):
        labels[(i, j)] = QtGui.QLabel('label {},{}'.format(i, j))
        gridLayout.addWidget(labels[(i, j)], i, j)
```

If I wanted to modify the first label of the first column and row I would just need to do it like this

```
labels[(1,1)].setText("modified")
```